# Wifi functionality

Tags: android, wifi, apn

Does anyone knows if the wifi networks for android phones are based on `Access Point Names` (APN) ?  I ask because in my android application I plan to overwrite some fields in all APN's to disable cellular network, but I still want to have available the wifi for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AFAIK`, WiFi is independent from APN settings, i.e., if you mess with the APN settings WiFi will still work (cf. the APNdroid application).